# is_file always returning false due to separator character (\)

Tags: php

I have images in my linux server, the images exists but the paths are having this separator character: "\" so is_file is always returning false even if the image exists. If I remove that separator character manually is_file is working fine, how can I fix this programmatically? i tried to remove the character using string replace but that character seems to be not working as a regular character, any other solution? 
Important: I need to keep my images as them are now, I can't run an script in order to modify their url or something like that. Thanks.

Example of image url: "test_1/6472647627/M_26199358_647364743773_4345.png"
IMPORTANT: this website (stackoverflow) is editing my image path, in the original path there is a "/" character but it is changed to "/" only.
[image: please see the character in this image]

Comment: `echo str_replace('\\', '/', 'test_1/6472647627/M_');` should do the trick.

Comment: No @RolandStarke because my path have the other character, this website is masking the character, I don't know why but it is `\`

Comment: Please see the image that I added in my post to see the character. It is not the regular / character.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case i would use `echo stripslashes('test_1\/6472647627\/M_')` (But i am not entirely sure, It depends on how the string was generated. Most of the time there is function to reverse it. Could also be `echo json_decode('"test_1\/6472647627\/M_"')`)